# Unstable Miglayout -- make two grow columns of the same size

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I have this simple MigLayout:

[image]

The two last components (JScrollPanes) should have the same width. But in fact, if I resize the window, they are randomly jumping. Is it possible to make their width equal? How else can I arrange components to make this look symmetrical?

Comment: Do you actually need to use migLayout? Or just want the output? Does it matter for you that the solution uses other layout such as border layout and grid or box layout?

Comment: You can achieve this simple panel using the built-in **GridBagLayout** or by mixing the **BorderLayout** and **GridLayout**. Check my answer.

Comment: I will have more controls here, this is very simplified to isolate the problem.

Comment: Post the code that builds your GUI as text.

Answer (score 4):

You need your columns to use the same `sizegroup`/`sg` in your column constraints. This way both columns will always have the same width.

Like this:

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[sizegroup main, grow][sizegroup main,grow]"[][][][grow]"));
```

See also the [MigLayout Cheatsheet](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/mavensite/docs/cheatsheet.html) about `sizegroup`.

Comment: works perfectly and solved a problem I was having

Comment: Thank you for this tip. Works perfect for me as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time I prefer to use the built-in facilities of java rather than mixing much further complex libraries and dependencies for such simple cases. I think when you can achieve the solution with a trivial effort like this it's not needed to use third party libraries such as MIG. This preference comes from the situation you are in: not so many people work with a purchased tools, so you can not get so many help from the community.

I know this question asks about `MigLayout` but I preferred to show that there is no need to use that for this simple situation. MIG library is rich and have some useful components which can make your life easier but when it comes to layouts I prefer pure java.

Sampling your layout using pure `BorderLayout` and `GridLayout`:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setBounds(50, 50, 500, 400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(createSpacerPanel(10, 10), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.add(createSpacerPanel(10, 10), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.add(createSpacerPanel(10, 10), BorderLayout.EAST);
        f.add(createSpacerPanel(10, 10), BorderLayout.WEST);
        f.add(new MainPanel());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JPanel createSpacerPanel(int width, int height){
        JPanel spacer = new JPanel();
        spacer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        return spacer;
    }
}

class MainPanel extends JPanel{

    public MainPanel() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        northPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 60));
        northPanel.add(new JLabel("Class Expression: "), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JTextArea classExpressionTextArea = new JTextArea();    
        classExpressionTextArea.setSize(10, 40);
        northPanel.add(new JScrollPane(classExpressionTextArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");
        northPanel.add(calculateButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JPanel definitionPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10,10));       
        definitionPanel.add(new JLabel("Definitions Found: "), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JTextArea definitionsTextArea = new JTextArea();        
        definitionPanel.add(new JScrollPane(definitionsTextArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel signaturePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10,10));    
        signaturePanel.add(new JLabel("Target Signature: "), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JTextArea targetTextArea = new JTextArea();
        signaturePanel.add(new JScrollPane(targetTextArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(1,1,10,10);
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(gridLayout);
        centerPanel.add(definitionPanel);
        centerPanel.add(signaturePanel);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout(10,10));
        add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);      
    }
}
```

And the fully resizable output:

[image]

The same can be achieved using `GridBagLayout` which is similar to `MigLayout` in the way of thinking about the layout and positioning and spanning components over grid cells.

Hope this would be helpful.