# Center a MigLayout with two columns

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I am trying to center the gap between two columns in a MigLayout. They should be aligned towards the center of the screen, but somehow I can't get it to actually be centered. Here's my code:

```
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        super("MigLayout Problems");

        String lc = "wrap 2, fill, al 50% 50%";
        String cc = "[right]15[left]";
        String rc = "[]5[]";

        JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
        subPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout(lc, cc, rc));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Some text");
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
        area.setText("This belongs to label1");
        subPanel.add(label);
        subPanel.add(area);

        add(subPanel);

        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

But the result I get looks like this:

```
|----------------------------|-----------------------------|
|           |Some text|  |This belongs to label1|          |
|                                                          |
|----------------------------|-----------------------------|
```

What I want is something like this:

```
|----------------------------|-----------------------------|
|                |Some text|   |This belongs to label1|    |
|                                                          |
|----------------------------|-----------------------------|
```

So to clarify, that gap between the two components is supposed to be centered in the panel. What am I missing here?

Comment: The varying component size makes the difference. You can type something in the text area and you will notice that the alignment changes. I think GridLayout will be a better option for you.

Comment: You  may like to refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249598/unstable-miglayout-make-two-grow-columns-of-the-same-size

Comment: Thanks @HiteshA.Bosamiya that worked perfectly!